# Dúvida sobre uma GLMM

Tags: r, modelagem, glm

Estou rodando esse modelo no R:

```
modelogeral<-lmer(lognplanta~Clas_renda*sexo*idade*ocupacao*escolaridade*Clas_npessoas*(1|comunidade),data=bruno)
```

Aparece a seguinte mensagem:

> fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 668 columns / coefficients
> boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

O que isso significa?

Comment: Como a mensagem diz, veja `help('isSingular')` para o significado de fits singulares. O tema é difícil e creio que o melhor é começar pela documentação e seguir os links dessa página. Esta pergunta é mais apropriada para o [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) a comunidade do Stack Exchange para perguntas de Estatística, o SO e o SO em Português são para perguntas de código.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @Bruno, a especificação do seu modelo está errado. Ademais, vc está colocando uma interação para todas as variáveis.
Faça:
`modelogeral<-lmer(lognplanta~Clas_renda+sexo+idade+ocupacao+escolaridade+Clas_npessoas + (1|comunidade),data=bruno)`
e o seu modelo deve rodar. Depois disso, você pode colocar as interações (`*`) nos seus efeitos fixos. mas nunca multiplique a parte aleatória também, isto é *(1|comunidade). O fato da matriz ser singular, significa que ela não admite inversa (não admite solução). Em termos práticos, tem muitos parâmetros estimando ao mesmo tempo.